# Timestamp parsing in Java/Scala for Spark-csv

Tags: java, apache-spark, timestamp

I am reading CSV files with spark-csv and one column is a timestamp with values like

```
Aug-02-2016 04:12:03:232 PM (CEST)
```

Of course this is rather non-standard, so I have to use the option of spark-csv

```
dateFormat: specifies a string that indicates the date format to use writing dates or timestamps. Custom date formats follow the formats at java.text.SimpleDateFormat. This applies to both DateType and TimestampType. If no dateFormat is specified, then "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S".
```

How can I specify this format?

I tried

```
'mm-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.S PM (CEST)'
```

without success.

Comment: I'm not sure this is supported given my Googling so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refer to the [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) doc for the formats you can specify.

In your case, I think it would be something like:

```
String format = "MMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss:SSS a (z)"
```